# Ubuntu won't ever start

Tags: boot, bootloader

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04.

It worked fine until I rebooted the computer using Windows and GRUB disappeared. I followed a guide and tried to solve the problem with a Boot Repair Live Disk, but I could only get a white screen when trying to start the OS. Could anyone please help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8, 8.1, and 10 sometimes override the system main boot loader on some computers. Your computer should have an option to boot from certain EFI files, or choose from a boot menu using EFIs found in the boot partitions. There you can navigate the boot partition and find either of 2 EFI files I found a link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) to build EFI files and make them default. I don't know about functionality with all Ubuntu distros.

**P.S.** Please give computer information for more help on boot help from us.